# ASP.NET MVC - AJAX Submit Form does not fire appropriate event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my personDetails.cshmtl file, I have the following form:

```
<form id="userUpdateForm" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Details</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="authorisedCheckbox" value="Authorised" id="authCheck" />Authorised<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="enabledCheckbox" value="Enabled" id="eCheck" />Enabled<br />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="personId" id="idCheck" value='@ViewData["personId"]'>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="Save Changes">
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

I then have Javascript further down the page as follows:

```
$('#userUpdateForm').submit(function (e) {
        var personDetails = {
            Enabled: $('#eCheck').val(),
            Authorised: $('#authCheck').val(),
            Id: $('#idCheck').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= Url.Action("submitForm", "Home") %>',
            data: JSON(personDetails),
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("A problem occured when submitting the form.");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

The Javascript is meant to fire when the Submit button is hit. First the method 'submitForm' in the 'HomeController' is fired, before it redirects back to 'Index' also in the 'HomeController', which just outputs a view.

The 'submitForm' currently resembles the following:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult submitForm(JsonResult jsonForm)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("made it here");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonForm);
            return View();
        }
```

So my question is: what am I missing with the current form to make the AJAX event fire? I'm fairly sure it is not currently firing as there is no alert and nothing output on the console from the method it's supposed to hit.

I would rather not change the form itself too much as I currently have another bit of Javascript that sets the checkboxes to checked onload where appropriate.

EDIT: I fixed the method with Stephen Muecke's advice. What I'm trying to do here is: hit button -> submit details to my submitForm method -> submitForm method takes details and does some stuff in the database -> return success when finished -> on success, redirected from personDetails.cshtml to index.cshtml.

Comment: `success: function (result) {
                '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
            }` is not doing anything. Is this a typo? Have you checked your network tab to see if the ajax call is firing, and what's in the response body? That would be the simplest way to see. Also, why is your ajax method accepting a "JsonResult" object? That should be the _return_ type. It should _accept_ a viewmodel object corresponding to the form fields.

Comment: And you shouldn't return an entire view from an ajax method - that will return a whole HTML page with all the tags - you can't insert that into your page. You should either return some Json data (using a JsonResult) or a partial view.

Comment: Finally, rather than doing `return false;` from the end of your submit method, it's safer to put `e.preventDefault();` as the first line of the method. This ensures there's no chance at all of it doing a normal postback before the Javascript has had time to complete.

Comment: You cannot mix aspx (`<%= Url.Action("submitForm", "Home") %>` and razor (`@Url.Action("Index", "Home")`). but what are you trying to do here. You call a method that returns a view but never do anything with it.

Comment: I changed it to url: '@Url.Action("submitForm", "Home")', and it's now hitting my method, thanks. edited question again to reflect what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user3316147 Ok now I see what you're trying to achieve. Design question: Why do you make an ajax call, then when it returns, immediately redirect to another page? If you'd just made a conventional postback instead of ajax, you could do everything you need in a single trip to the server (with a redirect to the other view at the end), instead of the two that you have now. This architecture is really a waste of processing time and bandwidth.

Comment: @ADyson the use of AJAX is an externally composed constraint. as for the rest, I'm very new to/inexperienced with AJAX and the ASP.NET entity framework so there's a good chance my code has a nonstandard structure as a result of that. the basic idea is to find some way with AJAX/the controller to submit the form, do some processing behind then redirect to the home page somehow

Answer (score 2):

You need to create one other class that should contain all the properties that you are posting to submitForm action method.

currently you are using JsonResult class that doesn't contain the properties that you trying to post so here ModelBinder will not bind the data. reference [Model Binder](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/831158/MVC-Model-Binder)..Great articles ...love it ....

```
   public class personDetails {
        public string Enabled {get;set;}
        public string Authorised {get;set;}
        public string Id {get;set;}
    } 
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult submitForm(personDetails ObjpersonDetails)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("made it here");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonForm);
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

Model:

```
public class MyModel{
        public string Id {get;set;}
        public string Authorised {get;set;}
        public string Enabled {get;set;}
    }
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult submitForm(MyModel model)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("made it here");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonForm);
            return View();
        }
```

Script:

```
$('#userUpdateForm').submit(function (e) {
        var personDetails = {
            Id: $('#idCheck').val(),
            Authorised: $('#authCheck').val(),
            Enabled: $('#eCheck').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("submitForm", "Home")',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ model: personDetails })
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = "/home/index/";              
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("A problem occured when submitting the form.");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```